# Issue in facebook logout

Tags: android, facebook

I made a login page with normal ID+password as well as Facebook login button. I saved a SharedPrefrerence string as "option" with value as 0 or 1 to recognize if user logged in as normal or facebook button. For logout, my layout has an icon in actionbar which when clicked opens another fragment which has a button for logout. The problem is when user logged in via Facebook button instead of going to the fragment having logout button, user logs out as soon as the icon (in actionbar) is clicked. It doesn't go to the other fragment with logout button.

```css
Fragment with logout button

public class Prof_settings extends Fragment{
 
 private SQLiteHandler db;
 private SessionManager session;
 Button logout;
 public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyApp_Settings";
 String option;
 
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
   Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
  View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.prof_settings, null);
  
  
  // SqLite database handler
  db = new SQLiteHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

  // session manager
  session = new SessionManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
  
  SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);
  option = settings.getString("option", "");

  if (!session.isLoggedIn()) {
   logoutUser();
  }
  
  logout = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.logout);
  logout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    logoutUser();
   }
  });
  
  
  
     return v;
  
 }
 
 private void logoutUser() {
  
  if(option.equals("1")){ //for facebook login
   
   LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
         Intent login = new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class);
         startActivity(login);
         getActivity().finish();
   
  }else if(option.equals("0")){  // for normal login
   
  
   session.setLogin(false);

   db.deleteUsers();

   
   // Launching the login activity
   Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class);
   startActivity(intent);
   getActivity().finish();
  }
  
  
 }
 
 
 
 
 
 

}
```

```html
First Layout Code

public class ProfileFrag extends Fragment{
 
 ImageView pic, grid, list, calender, map;
 LinearLayout LL_grid, LL_list;
 GridView GV;
 TextView profile_name;
 
 private SQLiteHandler db;
 private SessionManager session;
 
 String option, name;
 Bundle bundle;
 public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyApp_Settings";

    
 
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setHasOptionsMenu(true);
 }
 
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  
  View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.frag_profile, null);
  
  profile_name = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.profile_name);
  
  SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);
  option = settings.getString("option", "");
  
  if(option.equals("1")){
   
   name = settings.getString("name", "");
   
   profile_name.setText(name);
   
  }else if(option.equals("0")){
   
      // SqLite database handler
      db = new SQLiteHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

      // session manager
      session = new SessionManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

      // Fetching user details from SQLite
      HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();

      name = user.get("name");

      // Displaying the user details on the screen
      profile_name.setText(name);
  }
  
  
////////////////////////////////// Settings Icon Function Starts //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
 
 
 @Override
 public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);
  super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
  
  case R.id.settings:
   Prof_settings newFragment = new Prof_settings();//global variable

   FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
           fragmentManager.popBackStack();
           FragmentTransaction ft =fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
   ft.replace(R.id.fragment_place, newFragment,"Order");
   ft.commit();

  default:
   break;
  }
  
  return true;
  
 }
 
 
/////////////////////////////////////////////// Settings Icon Function Ends //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it resolved by inserting the isLoggedin() method inside the SharedPreference option condition.

```html
if(option.equals("0")){
   
   if (!session.isLoggedIn()) {
    logoutUser();
   }
   
}
```